# In laymen terms what is meant by Backing Object?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring framework. I was trying to retrieve **a backing object** for the current form from the given request but could not understand what is meant by the term backing object

Comment: There is no reason to use 'layman's terms' here. This is computer programming. We use computer programming terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an object which will have the data of your form. It is automatically initialized so you don't have to get data from form and set it to object's fields.

In servlets we need to get data as:

```
request.getParameter(String name);
```

then we have to initialize the respective field.

but in spring this step is done by spring.

Answer (score 1):

A backing bean, or backing object is the Java object that holds the form properties when you submit the form. Your form properties are bound to it by the controller usually by specifying the object in the controller method interface and using annotations.

For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("user")
                        User user, BindingResult result) {
```

`user` in this case is the backing object.

Answer (score 0):

Its the java object that form fields get put into when a form post occurs, in Spring MVC